# Sum of two dynamic array values in python

Tags: python

In DB , i am storing the values like this:

```
 1.{scheduled_activity:{
     fields_to_track:{
    planning_parameters:{
       value: 100}
  }
}
}

2.     {scheduled_activity:{
     fields_to_track:{
        planning_parameters:{
       value: 100}
      }
    }
   }
```

I want to add the two values and store it another list:

This is what i have done:

```
final_total_yield = []
try:
   sch_act = item["scheduled_activity"]
   for pp in data['fields_to_track']['planning_parameters']:
       final_total_yield.append(pp['value'])
```

Now it is just appending the values. But i want to sum the value.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect.

```
final_total_yield = []
total = 0
try:
   sch_act = item["scheduled_activity"]
   for pp in data['fields_to_track']['planning_parameters']:
       final_total_yield.append(pp['value'])
       total += pp['value']

print('Sum = ', total)
```

Comment: All i need to add the two values(i.e 100 + 100 = 200) I need to display